# Search in dictionary on a variety of conditions Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, search, conditional-statements

I have simple dictionary

`var countOfR = ["R0": 0, "R1": 0, "R2": 0, "R3": 0, "R4": 0, "R5": 0, "R6": 0]`

I need to check this dictionary by multiple conditions. For example, next statement works perfectly:

```
for index in countOfR {
        if index == ("R0",2) || index == ("R1",2) || index == ("R2",2) || index == ("R3",2) || index == ("R4",2) || index == ("R5",2) || index == ("R6",2) {
            type = "P"
```

This will find one "pair". But next I need to check for "two pairs" - "PP". It's terrible to write something like this:

```
if index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R1",2) || index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R2",2) || index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R3",2) || index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R4",2) || index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R5",2) || index == ("R0",2) && index == ("R6",2) || ...
```

and so on... I also need to search for "pair and trine", "three pairs" and many others.
For better understanding:

`["R0": 1, "R1": 2, "R2": 1, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 1, "R6": 0]` is "P",

`["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 0, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]` is "P" too,

`["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 2, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]` is "PP"

How can I solve this task? Please, give me some advice!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193959/discussion-on-question-by-george-search-in-dictionary-on-a-variety-of-conditions).

Comment: @BhargavRao He doesn't have enough reputation to use the chat...

Comment: @Alex, I've added them [explicitly to the write access list :)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/193959/discussion-on-question-by-george-search-in-dictionary-on-a-variety-of-conditions?tab=access).

Comment: @BhargavRao Interesting, didn't know that was a thing. Is that something I can control on chatrooms I make?

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately, nope. [There's a feature-request for that, though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257949/4099593).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *something like this* makes no sense as it never gets `true`. Your `index` (or what name it might be) cannot be *equal* to two different things at the same time.

I guess you just need to count the number of entries whose value is `2`.

You can write something like this:

```
func getType(_ countOfR: [String: Int]) -> String {
    let pairs = countOfR.filter{$0.value == 2}.count
    let trines = countOfR.filter{$0.value == 3}.count
    let type = String(repeating: "P", count: pairs) + String(repeating: "T", count: trines)
    return type
}
print(getType(["R0": 1, "R1": 2, "R2": 1, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 1, "R6": 0]))
//->P
print(getType(["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 0, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]))
//->P
print(getType(["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 2, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]))
//->PP
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with your conditions, and filter the main dictionary by comparing the condition dictionary. Type will be create based on the filtered result count.

```
var condition = ["R0":2,"R1":2,"R2":2,"R3":2,"R4":2,"R5":2,"R6":2]

let test1 = ["R0": 1, "R1": 2, "R2": 1, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 1, "R6": 0]// is "P",
let count1 = test1.filter { index in condition.contains(where: { $0 == index }) }.count
let type1 = String(repeating: "P", count: count1)
print(type1)//P

let test2 = ["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 0, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]// is "P" too,
let count2 = test2.filter { index in condition.contains(where: { $0 == index }) }.count
let type2 = String(repeating: "P", count: count2)
print(type2)//P

let test3 = ["R0": 1, "R1": 0, "R2": 2, "R3": 1, "R4": 0, "R5": 2, "R6": 0]// is "PP"
let count3 = test3.filter { index in condition.contains(where: { $0 == index }) }.count
let type3 = String(repeating: "P", count: count3)
print(type3)//PP
```